# Entire function of finite order omitting a non-zero value

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Does there exist a non-constant entire function of finite order having zeros of multiplicity at least $k+1,$ where $k$ is a positive integer, such that it omits at least one non-zero value in $\mathbb{C}?$

I am trying to construct an example but the condition on zeros is making it hard to check. Of course, there are infinitely many entire functions omitting a non-zero value in $\mathbb{C}$ when the condition of multiple zeros is dropped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a function does not exist.

An entire function of finite order which omits a non-zero value $c$ is necessarily of the form $f(z) = c + e^{p(z)}$ with a polynomial $p$.  (This follows for example from the [Hadamard factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem#Hadamard_factorization_theorem).)

Then  $f$ has infinitely many zeros, but $f'(z) = p'(z)  e^{p(z)}$ has only finitely many zeros, so almost all zeros of $f$ are simple.

Comment: Could you explain why  f of the form $f(z)=c+e^{p(z)}$ would be having infinitely many zeros?

Comment: @galaxy--: $f(z)$ is zero if $p(z)$ is equal to any of the (infinitely many) complex logarithms of $-c$.

Comment: Oh of course, thank you

Comment: @galaxy--: You can also use heavy machinery like Picard's theorem: If $f$ omits the two values $c$ and $\infty$ then all other values are taken infinitely often.

Comment: Big Picard was what first crossed my mind when seeing the question’s title, thank you for confirming that it’d also be possible with that